# PHPMyAdmin become unresponsive due to InnoDB table metadata lock in bulk INSERT / DELETE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run a long query in phpmyadmin, I can't access any other table through phpmyadmin in a different window or even browser.

Why is that? Can I fix it?

UPDATE:
some more details:
 - The table I'm running a query on is Innodb
 - I'm able to connect through command line
 - The long query is a DELETE which takes a couple of hours to finish

UPDATE2:
I've done some testing from the command line and have loaded into the table from a dump file while trying to open phpmyadmin, which also didn't work. When looking at `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I see there's a query stuck:

| 36732 | root                 | localhost      | db_name | Query   |   17 | Waiting for table metadata lock | SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 30                                           |

So I guess my problem is that the InnoDB table is locked, although it's an InnoDB table and the dump file is a bunch of Insert operations one after the other. I assume it's some sort of configuration problem?

Comment: Phpmyadmin allows to access multiple table from multiple windows simultanously. I guess you might have issue with installation

Comment: Or please follow correct installtion steps, you might be missing assigning preveliges

Comment: Because your tables are locked. Not a phpmyadmin issue.

Comment: "Because your tables are locked": probably, but it depends on whether the the offending statement updates the table(s). Also, your PHP session is locked too (applies only when trying to open another window in the same browser, not when using separate browsers).

Comment: @N.B. It's an innodb table and I'm running a delete on it. it shouldn't be locked, should it?

Comment: Now you gave us more info. The next thing I'd conclude is that all resources are dedicated to MySQL to delete the records. Nothing's free to serve the other request. Please edit your question and try to include as much info as you can.

Comment: @N.B. Added some more details, but really not sure what to include. What do you mean all resources are dedicated for the delete? how is that possible?

Comment: DELETE is a special case, InnoDB does lock tables when it has to. Are you wrapping those deletes in transactions or are you just running one by one? Can you post exact queries that you use and the sequence you use them in?